# How to create C# desktop application setup file along with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, desktop-application, setup-deployment

I created a C# application for my client with a database so I created a setup file which runs fine on my PC, but on my client's PC, it shows this error error msg

[image: error message]

I need to submit it to my client but it's showing this error; I think I am having problems with my connection string or during setup creation.

Can anyone here help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When working on your PC, are you connecting to a database residing on your PC?

Comment: Using poor quality images is not a good practice to ask questions, edit your question and post the error as a text or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: Refer to this question, you may find what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832375/clickonce-prerequisites-where-is-sql-server-express-2014-localdb

Answer (score 0):

When creating the setup file.. you need to include the database files `.mdf` files in the setup. [this video explains it well](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20create%20setup%20file%20with%20sql%20database%20in%20c%23&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsa8oF8jcwLK8yDxr5yAtBx0-R_wxA%3A1655420754188&ei=UrerYoaCC7eJ9u8Picaa8Ao&oq=c%23%20setup%20file%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYCDIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yCAgAEB4QBxAFMgYIABAeEAgyBggAEB4QCDIGCAAQHhAIMgYIABAeEAgyBggAEB4QCDoHCAAQRxCwAzoGCAAQHhAPOggIABAeEAgQBzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEB4QFjoICAAQHhAPEBZKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQvCVY9H5goaYBaAZwAXgAgAGbAogBghiSAQQyLTEzmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz#kpvalbx=_2berYpb8HMeq9u8Pko2XgAY16)

Comment: I already tried it but i didn't work in client Machine